# Writing a jquery plugin to do text replacement

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Let's say hypothetically I want to replace all 'a' in a string with 'b'

'abc' -> 'bbc'

I want to run this on various strings:

```
var str1= 'abc'
var str2= 'adf'
var str3= 'abvxvb'
var str4= 'ae54'
```

I'm trying to write a jquery plugin that does this.

So I can do `str1.a_to_b();` and get the desired result. (Actually having the syntax in another form is fine too).

There's something wrong with my attempted syntax:

```
jQuery.fn.a_to_b = function(expr) {
    return this.each(function() {
        this = this
        .replace(/a/ig, "b");
    });
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery methods (attached to jQuery.fn) work with html elements, not strings. You want a static function (which you attach to jQuery itself)

```
jQuery.aToB = function(str) {
   return str.replace(/a/g, "b");
}

alert($.aToB("abc"))
```

Alternatively you can extend String.prototype (not recommended, since this is a potential conflict source)

```
String.prototype.toB = function() {
   return this.replace(/a/g, "b");
}

alert("abc".toB())
```

Answer (score 0):

With a different sintax, maybe you can use the following

```
jQuery.a_to_b = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/a/ig, "b");
};
```

And after that you could call

```
var str1= 'abc';

str1 = jQuery.a_to_b(str1);
```

and you would have the new value stored in str1